# why can't imagejpeg save to a folder?

Tags: php, compiler-errors, gd, thumbnails

I've been truble shooting this for hours and i've been all over the web trying to find the solution to this... Im writing a thumbnale generater in php that should generate a gray scale image and a non gray scale, but i've been running into this error. I have already changed my permissions to 777 and chown to nobody and admin. and this function works as long as I over write an image by the same name, but it cannot store in a file for some reason.

here is the error:

```
imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/images
/thumb/rollover' for writing: Is a directory
```

here is the code i'm working with.

```
  $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($grayscale_path);

            imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);

            imagejpeg($img, realpath($this->gallery_path .'/thumb/rollover/'));


            imagedestroy($img);
```

also i've checked many many times to see if the path is correct and it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to append a filename,

```
 header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
 imagejpeg($img, realpath($this->gallery_path .'/thumb/rollover/filename.jpg'));
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your quick response. So I no longer get that error, but It just prints out a bunch of non sense text to my screen now and does not save anything. I added your changes. any other advise? do you think that XAMPP might have an out dated version of the gd library? and if so how do i update that?

Comment: @AlexW.H.B - you need to set header(). See my post.

Comment: I got it to work, and you are exactly right. It was the header that was not allowing it to work properly. thank you so much for your help! my code is working flawlessly now, and i give you the credit. :)

Comment: @ AlexW.H.B Buddy! It is not about credit. I'm Glad! you got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

in imagejpeg, second parameter is not a path to a dir, but to the actual file
you must add "filename.jpg" at the end of the path.